# Reading and set the material content of a .blend

Tags: python, materials

My object is saved in .blend file with the material "mat1". I apply another material for my object (without my Register file). Now I want with python, apply the material "original" (assigned in the .blend my object) without close and reopen my file.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand: You have two objects (obj1 and obj2), both of which have mat3 applied to them. You also have two additional materials - mat1 and mat2, and you want obj1 to have mat1 and obj2 to have mat2 applied to them, all with a Python script?

Comment: I changed the description of my request, perhaps it is clearer